# error C2448: function-style initializer appears to be a function definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I have the following piece of code -

```
void CommandProcessor::ReplacePortTag((void *) portID)
{
    std::string temp = std::string.empty();
    int start = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<CommandProcessor::fileContents.length(); i++)
    {
        if (CommandProcessor::fileContents.substr(i,6) == "<port>")
        {
            temp += CommandProcessor::fileContents.substr(start,i-start);
            temp += portID;
            start = i+6;
        }
    }
    temp += CommandProcessor::fileContents.substr(start+6,CommandProcessor::fileContents.length()-start-6);
    CommandProcessor::fileContents = temp;
}
```

When I try to compile I'm getting the error -

```
error C2448: 'CommandProcessor::ReplacePortTag' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
```

I am unable to figure out where I'm going wrong. What do I modify to fix this error?

Comment: If `fileContents` is not `static`, I recommend leaving out the `CommandProcessor::`.

Comment: This `std::string temp = std::string.empty();` also doesn't make much sense. Just declare it like `std::string temp`.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to std::string temp = ""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax means you are C-style casting the variable `portID` to a `void*`

```
void CommandProcessor::ReplacePortTag((void *) portID)
```

If the argument is supposed to be a `void*` your function declaration should be

```
void CommandProcessor::ReplacePortTag(void* portID)
```